# What's the difference between environment variables shown in `systemctl --user show-environment` and those set by `export`?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Command `systemctl --user show-environment` can return a list environment variables. But I usually use `export` command to set environment variables and view the value using `echo $...`. I ask this question because I recently noticed that the environment variables from the former are different from the latter, and I can't change the value of former environment variables using `export` command. So, can you please tell me what's the difference between the two types of environment variables? How can I change the value of environment variables of the former type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables set using the `export` command are accessible only by the shell (and sub-shells of that shell) which created them.

[`export` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/export.1p.html)

> The shell shall give the export attribute to the variables
> corresponding to the specified names, which shall cause them to
> be in the environment of subsequently executed commands. If the
> name of a variable is followed by =word, then the value of that
> variable shall be set to word.

Systemd on the other hand, keeps its own environment variable block and does not read files like `.bashrc`, these environment variables are passed down to the spawned processes. [`systemctl` man page - Environment Commands section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html).

There are several ways to set systemd environment variables: [Arch wiki - Systemd/User Environment Variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Environment_variables).